# how to return a oracle table in a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I have a procedure which calls a function. This function returns a table and now in the procedure I want to select the entire table. I am doing this atm and I get uninitialised collection.

```
 procedure check_all (
      p_period IN RPT_EXT.PERIOD%type default rptsum_time - 1/24/12,
      p_days IN NUMBER default 1/24/12,
      p_data_ext IN VARCHAR2 default DATA_EXT_DE2,
      p_ext_no IN TWS_DIMENSION_DEFINES.EXT_NO%type default null,
      p_record_id IN RPT_EXT.RECORD_ID%type default null
  )
  as
  sql_statement varchar2(200);
  tab extraction_count_tab;
  begin
  tab := extraction_counts( p_period , p_days, p_data_ext, p_ext_no, p_record_id);
   sql_statement := 'select* from tab';
   execute immediate sql_statement; -- need to chacnge this
   dbms_output.put_line(chr(10));
   performance_check(p_period, p_days, p_data_ext);
  end check_all;
```

Comment: and select for what?

Comment: u want to iterate through that table?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you like to achieve ...
Do you like to use all records from `select * from tab` to call the procedure `performance_check` with them?

Then you should consider using a for-loop like this:

```
for rec in (
  select * from tab
           )
loop
   performance_check(rec.columnA, rec.columnB, ...)
end loop;
```

Or shall `performance_check` return a table, which you like to use?
In that case you´ll have to switch from procedure to a table-function, either a normal or pipelined.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm for documentation or f.e. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions for some samples.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its very unclear what you want to try but i tried to replicate the scenario. Hope it helps. I don't have workspace with me so pardon if any syntactical error.

```
PROCEDURE check_all(
    p_period    IN RPT_EXT.PERIOD%type DEFAULT rptsum_time - '1/24/12',
    p_days      IN NUMBER DEFAULT '1/24/12',
    p_data_ext  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT DATA_EXT_DE2,
    p_ext_no    IN TWS_DIMENSION_DEFINES.EXT_NO%type DEFAULT NULL,
    p_record_id IN RPT_EXT.RECORD_ID%type DEFAULT NULL )
AS
  sql_statement VARCHAR2(200);
  tab extraction_count_tab;
BEGIN
  tab           := extraction_counts( p_period , p_days, p_data_ext, p_ext_no, p_record_id);
  sql_statement := 'select * from TABLE(tab)';
  EXECUTE immediate sql_statement BULK COLLECT INTO tab; -- need to chacnge this
  dbms_output.put_line(chr(10));
  performance_check(p_period, p_days, p_data_ext);
END check_all;
```